# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Filter exception on Jboss

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have been using Tomcat 6 for all my application development and deployment purposed, but today decided to use JBoss as it seems to be more scalable.

But after configuring JBoss on my eclipse and deploying my application I get the following error,

Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Filter exception on Jboss

I added the server library in the server classpath and the error disappeared, but still the application fails to load, since spring doesn't initialize.

**UPDATE**

Now I am getting the following error, the application runs fine in Tomcat 6, this the stack trace I am getting,

```
2010-02-11 23:17:48,959 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/cric140].[action]] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '/login' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:968)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:168)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:885)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy.getDelegateAction(DelegatingActionProxy.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy.execute(DelegatingActionProxy.java:109)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.indiagames.inrev.auth.IRAuthFilter.doFilter(IRAuthFilter.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Can't seem to understand why spring fails to load, I have the following description in my web.xml,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/*Context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to **copypaste** the **full** and **unchanged** Exception, message and stacktrace.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the exception? The stack trace would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Check all of your spring bean configs inside every xml files under `classpath:spring/*Context.xml` whether you have defined a bean named `'/login'`.

If the spring bean xml definition files is inside a jar file, make sure the jar is available in your webapp and make sure those jars contain the spring bean definition.

Comment: As mentioned earlier the app runs fine in tomcat 6, all the definitions are present in the files.

Comment: What JBoss version are you using?

Comment: JBoss 5 has a different way on loading files inside jar file. You might want to try to deploy on JBoss 4 and see whether it works.